# Could not create lake database from synapse notebooks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

New to azure synapse, trying to create database (Managed table) from synapse notebook. I also added Storage blob data contributor for synapse workspace and specific user. I have attached the error details.

```
%%SQL
CREATE DATABASE sample
```

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://XXXXXXXXXX.dfs.core.windows.net/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createDatabase(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:193)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:137)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:124)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:153)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:60)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:218)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDatabaseCommand.run(ddl.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:228)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
```

Comment: There is another permission at Synapse Studio level you should add called ' 
Synapse Contributor'.  I would probably add Contributor at Resource Group level too.  Try those - you can always tighten up with lower granularity permissions (eg Synapse Apache Spark Administrator and others listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-workspace-synapse-rbac-roles).

Comment: Hi @wBob Therse are the permission which i have                                                
Synapse Workspace - Synapse Administrator, Synapse SQL Administrator, Synapse Apache Spark Administrator, Synapse Contributor, Synapse Compute Operator.                                                     ADLS GEN2 - Storage Blob data Owner, Storage Blob Data Contributor, Contributor, and Owner.                                                                                                             
Resource Group - Contributor, Storage Blob Data Contributor.

Comment: Are you saying those are the permissions you have or the options you can see?  Synapse Administrator is the most powerful at workspace level, so you do not need the others such ad SQL Admin and Apache Spark Admin.  I would guess one of them is missing, maybe not looking in the right place, eg the storage associated with your Synapse Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, that your account doesn't have enough permissions to the workspace. Can you please make sure to check whether the blob storage account role is assigned to **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** or not.

you can also go through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/565482/i-am-getting-error-while-running-the-spark-job-wit.html) for permissions.